# varnish 4.0 VCL error : Running VCC-compiler failed

Tags: wordpress, varnish, varnish-vcl

I use varnish 4.0, and following these operations,

vi /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
# Drop any cookies sent to WordPress.
sub vcl_recv {
     if ((req.url ~! "wp- (login | admin)")) {
         unset req.http.cookie;
     }
}

# Drop any cookies WordPress tries to send back to the client.
sub vcl_backend_response {
     if ((req.url ~! "wp- (login | admin)")) {
         unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
     }
}
```

I /etc/init.d/varnish restart when executing this command

Got this error message.

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
Syntax error at
('input' Line 33 Pos 1)
    if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
#-------------------------------------------

Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2

VCL compilation failed
 * Syntax check failed, not restarting
```

So，How to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As [documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/whats-new/upgrading.html#req-not-available-in-vcl-backend-response) says:

> req.* not available in vcl_backend_response
>
> req.* used to be available
>   in vcl_fetch, but after the split of functionality, you only have
>   'bereq.*' in vcl_backend_response.

Comment: I think that the link is outdated. Use this one: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/whats-new/upgrade-4.0.html?highlight=vcl_backend_response#backend-restarts-are-now-retry